# Mouse cursor seems to change keyboard input focus

Tags: windows, mouse, window-manager

Running 10.04 and 10.10 (maybe before these) I've noticed that for some dialogs to accept input the mouse cursor must be in the parent window.  This is the case even though from the window highlighting the dialog box is in focus.

Is there exposed configuration control for this behavior?  I'm particularly interested in GUI controls.  I've looked at mouse and window preferences - no joy.

Comment: are you running compiz?

Comment: Please append the necessary steps to replicate the problem to your question. That'd be tremendously helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled a feature called "focus follows mouse" at some point? The behavior you describe sounds like this option is turned on on your system. Check the window preferences, or else `gconf` (using `gconf-editor`) for a setting to that effect. Otherwise perhaps googling the term will help you.

Comment: No, I've used that mode on Solaris.  After Stefano's comment I tried some of the common apps and couldn't find a replication sequence that I could present.

Comment: How does one retract a question?

Comment: There's a "delete" link just under your question. Should be next to "close" and "edit"

Comment: But you could leave the question here, because it's a good question and has a correct answer. it might help others.